# XML Parse error on trying to get metadata from Federation

Tags: xml, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, shibboleth

On trying to get Metadata file from a federation, I get the following error

```
XMLTooling.ParserPool : fatal error on line 213849, column 12547, message: unable to connect socket for URL    'http://metadata.ukfederation.org.uk/ukfederation-metadata.xml'
OpenSAML.MetadataProvider.XML : error while loading resource (http://metadata.ukfederation.org.uk/ukfederation-metadata.xml): XML error(s) during parsing, check log for specifics
```

This is the entry I have in my shibboleth2.xml

```
<MetadataProvider type="XML" uri="http://metadata.ukfederation.org.uk/ukfederation-metadata.xml" 
                      backingFilePath="ukfederation-metadata.xml" reloadInterval="14400">
                        <MetadataFilter type="RequireValidUntil" maxValidityInterval="2592000"/>
                        <MetadataFilter type="Signature" certificate="ukfederation.pem"/>   
            </MetadataProvider>
```

My initial hunch was this is a firewall issue, but I am able to use wget/curl to download the Metadata file from the uri.

Comment: The uk federation metadata contains several entities and its size is (24+ Mb), maybe is a memory limit issue.

Comment: memory limit on our server ?

Comment: Did you solve it?